# how to make javascript object disappear when click on rest of page

Tags: javascript, toggle

How to change the following code so when clicking anywhere on the web page, the line "This is foo" will disappear, right now I have to click "Click here" to make it disappear.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here</a>
<div id="foo">This is foo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may wish to use something other than an `<a>` tag for a button, otherwise you need a `preventDefault();` mechanism in your function or a hack like `onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');return false;"`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to bind the click event to the `body` element for it to fire when you click anywhere on the page.

Comment: but I want to bind the click event to the button as well

Comment: @ArgonneFarm ... that would be redundant, since your button is in the body, but you are free to do so if it suits your fancy in case you want to change/remove the global click behavior later.

Comment: i mean when clicking the button, it will toggle, but when clicking the body, it always hides, no toggle

Comment: @ArgonneFarm : Those will need to be two separate events: one on the body that always hides the element and another on the button that toggles it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use document object for attaching event handler

```
document.onclick = function(){
   var e = document.getElementById('foo');
   e.style.display = ((e.style.display != 'none') ? 'none' : 'block');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<body onclick="foo();">
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here</a>

    <div id="foo" style="display:none;" >This is foo</div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var b = false;

function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
     if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    b = true;
}

function foo() {
    var e = document.getElementById('foo');
    if(!b) e.style.display = 'none';
    b=false;
}
```

And this bit of css:

```
body,html
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/57ZpS/8/

Comment: Mageek, I tried it, it works, except on the very first page load, need to click "Click here" twice in order to make "This is foo" disappear, after that, everything is fine, just click once will do, any idea?

Comment: Yes, you must specify `style="display:block;"` for the div (instead of none in my example). (There is another way if you don't want to put this style)